# django Admin list object print

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My user model is as follows.

```
**model.py**
class User(models.Model):
    #user_idx = models.AutoField('user-num', primary_key=True)
    user_idx = models.OneToOneField(Counsel, primary_key=True, db_column="user_idx", related_name="useridx" , on_delete="models.DO_NOTHING")
    district_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'


           verbose_name_plural = "USER"

class Counsel(models.Model):
    counsel_idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_sub_idx = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_idx = models.IntegerField()
    counsel_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    counsel_contents = models.TextField()
    counsel_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COUNSEL_STATUS)
    answer_count = models.IntegerField()
    hit = models.IntegerField()
    user_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField()
    update_date = models.DateTimeField()
    deleted = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DELETE_STATUS)
```

The django Admin then created the source as follows:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_idx', 'show_firm_url', 'user_name',)

    def show_firm_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='/admin/user/view/{0}'>{1}</a>", obj.user_idx, obj.user_email)

    show_firm_url.short_description = 'E-mail'
```

The results are like images.
[image]

Counsel object (1494)
Please tell me how to get this number out.
Counsel object (1494) -----> 1494

Comment: Add `Counsel` model to your models in the question please

Comment: add Counsel model~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>override `__unicode__` to change what django renders for your model object</strike> => this method works for python2 not python3

override `__str__` to change what django renders for your model object

```
class User(models.Model):

    user_idx = models.OneToOneField(Counsel, primary_key=True, 
    db_column="user_idx", related_name="useridx" , on_delete="models.DO_NOTHING")
    district_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d" % self.user_idx.id  # id is field of Counsel object you want to show
```

In your case if you want to change what `Counsel` object represents you have to change that model to this one:

```
class Counsel(models.Model):
    counsel_idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_sub_idx = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_idx = models.IntegerField()
    counsel_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    counsel_contents = models.TextField()
    counsel_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COUNSEL_STATUS)
    answer_count = models.IntegerField()
    hit = models.IntegerField()
    user_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField()
    update_date = models.DateTimeField()
    deleted = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DELETE_STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d" % self.user_idx
```

Comment: @tigerJK if you want to change what `Counsel` object shows you have to add `__str__` to that model instead of `User` see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the [`__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__) method defined on a model instance whenever it needs to represent the model instance as a string:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ... your fields

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d" % self.user_idx.pk
```

`__unicode__()` only works if your are not running Django on Python3.

Comment: It's the version of Python that matters, not the version of Django.

Comment: Yes you are right of course, didnt think much when typing :)